# Deleting pandas series name

Tags: python, pandas, series

I have a series named `Names` that looks like this:

```
0    abc
1    def
2    ghi
Name: Names, dtype: object
```

I want to delete the name of the series. I want the series to look like this:

```
0    abc
1    def
2    ghi
dtype: object
```

I tried removing the name by doing this:

```
names.name = ''
```

But it still has an empty name:

```
0    abc
1    def
2    ghi
Name: , dtype: object
```

How do I get rid of the name? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the name to None:

```
names.name = None
```

Or [rename](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.rename.html#pandas.Series.rename) it:

```
names.rename(None, inplace=True)
```

Comment: This worked, thanks :)